# Is there a standard way of making a copy of file/folder permissions to apply/compare later?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, posix, chmod

I'm copying a bunch of files to a filesystem that doesn't support permissions. however, I will need to copy them to another filesystem which does support permissions a few years from now. at that point the current filesystem or its current state will be unavailable to me.
Is there a way to preserve them in an understandable and sane way that the next guy can understand and apply to the files?

I'm looking for something like this

```
./folder/
./folder/file-1
./folder/file-2
./folder.perms
```

Comment: You may find something that helps in : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/549577/27616 (edit: better answer, and creates a permissions files with the info in it)

Comment: Considered using a loopback filesystem or an archive which supports permissions (e.g. tar)?

Comment: @symcbean Yes. unfortunately that would result in a filesize that's not supported by e.g. fat32 and didn't want to get into the tedium of splitting tar files.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most portable format you could pick is probably to make a Posix-compliant tar archive.

But you first need to figure out exactly what permissions/attributes/flags you want to save.

Posix tar supports 'extended attributes' - but by default it doesn't support SELinux context.

Comment: What to you mean by *Posix tar*? Is that the [pax interchange format](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html#tag_20_92_13_01)?

Comment: Yes. GNU `tar --format=posix` will generate a `POSIX 1003.1-2001(pax)` format archive. That's _very_ portable and most likely supports all you need.